# Documentation for jQuery 'nth'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I mistakenly typed `$('div:nth(1)')` instead of `$('div:eq(1)')` on the main page of stackoverflow.com in a debug window. The results are same. I know that nth-child is different from eq. But what is 'nth'? I can't find its documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As jQuery uses Sizzle, I looked it up on their [docs](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation#wiki-selectors)

> :eq/:nth: Finds the nth element on the page (e.g. :eq(5) finds the 6th
>   element on the page).

You can also see it in the source:

```
Expr.pseudos["nth"] = Expr.pseudos["eq"];
```

Since it isn't documented in the jQuery documentation, should jQuery move away from using Sizzle, it may no longer have it.

Comment: In other words, they are aliases of each other.

Comment: @buffer: Actually, I should probably remove mine and just edit the comment about future-proofing into this one, if that's okay with you?